# Odoo 15 User form showing list of groups instead of group settings

Tags: forms, view, odoo, odoo-15

I'm using Odoo 15 and in my development environment the user form is showing group settings as usual, but in production a list with all the user's groups is shown instead.

Production (Wrong):
[image]

Development:
[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening?

I've restored the production database into my local environment, and the form is rendered as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the group settings are rendered by a method called `_update_user_groups_view` in `res.users`. When the context indicates that an install/update/uninstall is running, `groups_id` is rendered as a list.
Probably due to an error while updating, the context was indicating that an update was still running. After updating the system, the problem was solved.